# Rails Devise root/:username url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, url, devise

Is there a proper way to set Devise to redirect User profile to be accessible with `root/:username` ?

I know how to set devise to respond to `root/user/:username`, but do not know how to hide/takeoff the `/user` path.

Thank you !

Comment: you can use friendly_id gem for hiding the id's of user.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just for a redirection/urlhiding, maybe a easier way than adding a gem just for that exists ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to have url like:  `domain.com/jack` where `jack` is the name of a user, you need:

routes.rb

```
get '/:name' => 'users#show', as: :profile
```

users_controller.rb

```
def show
  User.find_by_name(params[:name])
end
```

in view

```
<%= link_to 'profile', profile_path(user.name) %>
```

or in controller actions

```
redirect_to profile_path(user.name)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I had in mind actually, but by doing that all other static pages like root.com/about will be considered as a :username. Manually escaping them is not very clever

Comment: You will want actually to escape pages like `/contacts /about_us /whatever_else_page`, in other cases where you'll have `posts resource` for example opening url at `.com/posts` should look for `posts#index` action as required by the routes file: `resources :posts`. Also I found a few times that the order you declare routes in file will have impact on your app. For example: declaring `get '/:name' => 'users#show'` before/after resources :posts might have different impact on app, it will be like trying to open a route first then if route jack is not defined it will go to profile_path.

Comment: That´s very interesting, thank you very much for the details. I guess you meant "post_path" in the last sentence. So I set each get for static with escape: true, and the ressource user in first (they are the smallest base, since users has_many post etc). Did I understand everything correctly ?

Comment: No, I meant profile_path, let's say you'll open url at .com/jack, in this case rails will probably look for a jack_path that normaly doesn't exists, so it will take it as param for `profile_path`. Why don't you try it, would be better instead of guessing.  About the `escape: true` can't say, never used it.

Comment: There is no way to hide the controller (say :yser) for a whole resources (new/edit/show) views ? Just arrived from a trip so I setted the thing and everything works well, I setted the get of each static page, then the get for user.

Comment: ".. and everything works well" - you mean you solved your issue?

Comment: Yes, everything is ok for the show view. Thank you a lot.
I'm wondering if all views of a controller can have the controller path escaped in the url other way than one by one.

Comment: well, not sure about that, I know that when I want to override a path I do it one by one but may be there is a better practice out there that I don't know of.